# Do cell carries have access to FaceTime information?

Tags: facetime, cellular-carriers

On the newest iPhone, do cell phone carriers have access to FaceTime call data (such as which caller initiated and ended a FaceTime call)?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Can you please clarify what exactly the issue is and what steps you've taken so far to resolve it?

Comment: Is there a way to determine who ended/hung up  a facetime call.

Answer (score 2):

FaceTime only needs Internet connection for audio and video calls therefore the only data your carrier receives is what server you connected to, which I don't think is what you are looking for. **You** are the only one having access to the FaceTime logs.

Comment: I know on the device it shows who initiated the cloud is there a way to find out who ended the call

Comment: It was either you or the other person, and most applications for communication don't show such information because it seems a little unnecessary. Don't you think it would be much easier to ask the other person whether they were the one who ended the call?